# submitting google ads code to db throws me to 403 forbidden page

Tags: php

Can someone see why is it then if i submit a normal string nothing happens but if i input the below code in the textarea field and hit submit i get showing the 403 forbidden error page? it works ok on my local wamp server but not on my live website.

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
```

here is my code

```
try {

            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE adsense SET code = :code') ;
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':code' => $code
                    ));


            //redirect to index page
                header('Location: adsense.php?action=UPDATED');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

what will fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: this question is tagged "mysql" and "pdo" so it seems like there's a perception there is something wrong with the sql. it's odd use case that requires updating every row in a table, but it's not necessarily wrong. not shown is the code that configures PDO to throw exceptions, so i guess we are to assume the `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` has been done.

Comment: so should i remove setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) is what you mean?

Comment: no, not what i meant. we don't see that its been done, and that is a typical oversight. we see very little in the way of steps that have been taken to debug the cause of the behavior. how is it that we have arrived at identifying his particular section of code as as the cause of a "403 forbidden page", which is typically due to the web server configuration and resource permissions, not a mysql error. it could be a cascade from this code, but what we really need to identify is which resource the webserver is rejecting access to.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: understand your point.

Comment: You need to look at your web-server's error log

Comment: in the root directory i cannot find error log